# Which ARIA role to within button

Tags: html, wai-aria

Which would be correct role to use within a button, so the `aria-label` attribute is used by screen readers.

```
<button class="favorite-button">
    <span class="material-symbols-outlined"
          aria-label="add to favorites"
          role="???">
        grade
    </span>
</button>
```

So I use a google font material symbol, without aria-label + role "grade" would be read to screen reader users.
Which role would be a suitable one in this case?

Comment: `button` role? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role

Comment: AFAIK the button tag is the element that receives focus (on which the browser may look for specific aria attributes, not the span. Also: I think that the aria role is implied from the button tag, so none is needed. I think setting the aria-label on the button should be sufficient.

Comment: Putting the role `button` on the span inside the button would make the sreen reader inform the hearer twice that it is a button, so that's not a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question implies that setting a `role` forces the `aria-label` to be read. That's not exactly true (although for `region` landmarks, some screen readers **don't** announce the landmark if it doesn't have an accessible name, so that's kind of the opposite of what your question implies - that the role won't be announced unless there's an `aria-label`.)

In your case, it's very simple. The role is already there because of the `<button>` element and the `aria-label` should be on the button itself.

```
<button class="favorite-button" aria-label="add to favorites">
  <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
    grade
  </span>
</button>
```

However, the above solution causes [WCAG 2.5.3 Label in Name](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#label-in-name) issue.  You will now have a button that visually displays "grade" but the screen reader will say "add to favorites".  The visible label won't match the screen reader text.

Can you provide more details on what you're trying to do?  Is the purpose of the button to add an element to a favorites list?  Or is the purpose of the button to show grades?  It sort of sounds like you need two separate interactive elements.  One to show the grade and one to add to favorites, but more detail is needed.

Comment: The "grade" icon is a star I use to mark an entry as favorite, not to grade the entry. So visible is a star icon, not a text "grade". I see why it might be confusing.
But I somehow didn't thought of putting the aria-label directly on the button.. Thanks.